# Can't find name dimension during the Integration of D3 PCP with Angular4

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to integrate d3 PCP chart in Angular 4 .During the integration i am getting error can not find dimension.Can any one suggest me where i am doing mistake:

```
// Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
  if (d === "name") return false;
  if (d === "Plant" || d === "Chemical" || d === "Pathway" || d === "Gene" || d === "Disease") {
    y[d] = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data.map(function(p) {
        return p[d];
      }))
      .range([h, 0]);
  } else {
    y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) {
        return +p[d];
      }))
      .range([h, 0]);
  }
  return true;
}));
```

Comment: if i will define private dimensions: Array<string>; then i am not getting any path of each dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the problem by changes that line
x.domain(this.dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d)